# Should %UserProfile%\Documents\WindowsPowerShell be in the path

Tags: powershell, windows-10

Sorry for this very basic question. Every installation of Windows 10 includes a folder *WindowsPowerShell* inside the per user *%UserProfile%\Documents* folder, yet it is not included in the Path variable for this user. So this is apparently not the location for user PS-scripts but more of development area (?). Where should user scripts go? Or should I add this manually?

Answer (score 0):

You can add any folder you want to your path.  Note that "Install-Script -Scope CurrentUser" would add $env:userprofile\documents\windowspowershell\scripts to the path, if you were to install a script from the Powershell gallery.